# One Line Basic SQL Pivot?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a database with rows as follows:

```
Milk
Eggs
Butter
Cheese
Bread
```

I want to pivot the entire row into a column appears as follows:

```
Milk Eggs Butter Cheese Bread
```

I have found a lot of examples using it with multiple columns and rows or based on select conditions. I haven't found any examples of how to just do one row, and I can't figure it out. Thanks for the help!

Edit:
The ways below work great but is there a way to do it and turn the row value into a column value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a modified version of the sample [here](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-2008/dynamic-pivot-in-tsql/).

```
DECLARE
    @SQL varchar(MAX),
    @ColumnList varchar(MAX)

SELECT @ColumnList=
       COALESCE(@ColumnList + ',','') + QUOTENAME(your_column_name)
FROM
(
       SELECT DISTINCT your_column_name
       FROM your_table 
) T


SET @SQL = '
WITH PivotData AS
(
       SELECT your_column_name
       FROM your_table
)
SELECT
    ' + @ColumnList + '
FROM
    PivotData
PIVOT
(
    MAX(your_column_name)
    FOR your_column_name
    IN (' + @ColumnList + ')
) AS PivotResult'

EXEC (@SQL)
```

P.S. I'd have to seriously question why I was doing this. :)

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks! The reason I am doing this is because I am creating a config file using information from the database and I only needed 1 row, but need to read it in as a column.

Answer (score 7):

```
select your_column_name+' ' from your_table for XML PATH ('')
```

Will return

```
Milk Eggs Butter Cheese Bread
```

Here's the whole script:

```
declare @Q as table 
(name varchar(50))

insert into @Q
values
('Milk'),
('Eggs'),
('Butter'),
('Cheese'),
('Bread')

select name+' ' from @Q for XML PATH ('')
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this and keep the names in a column?

Comment: @buzzzzjay what do you mean? The result is presented in one column

Comment: Do you mean this, perhaps? select (
select name+' ' from @Q for XML PATH ('')
) as col_name